# find how many parameters do i have train

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Suppose you have a `10x10x3` colour image input and you want to stack two convolutional layers with kernel size `3x3` with `10` and `20` filters respectively.

How many parameters do you have to train for these two layers?

Don't forget bias terms!

I've tried `(3*3*3+1) * (10+20)` but it's apparently not right.

Comment: It's apparently not wrong? So it's true?

Answer (score 0):

[How to calculate the number of parameters in the CNN?](https://medium.com/@iamvarman/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-in-the-cnn-5bd55364d7ca)

For each layer do:

```
n: kernel width
m: kernel length
l: no. input feature maps
k: no. output feature maps
no. parameters = (n*m*l+1)*k
```